# Add MacOS Support to Existing Android Studio Project

Tags: android-studio

How do you add a MacOS version of a Flutter/Dart project in Android Studio?  I can create a new project and move everything over but I wonder if there is a more elegant way to add the MacOS (and later Windows and Linux as they come available) to the existing project.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty ugly, but it worked for me.

1. Rename the directory for the existing project (the one containing Pubspec.yaml) to old.my_app
2. Create a new project, in the same place with the same parameters (i.e., my_app)
3. Move/rename the macos directory in the newly created project (i.e., my_app) to the old.my_app directory
4. Delete the my_app directory (not the old.my_app directory!)
5. Move/rename the old.my_app directory to my_app

Obviously, the new macos app will not have any of the code that runs in the AppDelegate.swift file (if any) but the Dart side will run and the app will build.